# Developing an android API backend with cloud endpoints in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

The background story: I have a nice client in a form of an android app, and now I want to create a backend that will use the Data Store service of google.
Now, I've created a simple backend module in android studio (SayHi example) which I've tested and works well.
My problem is how to proceed now. all the backend developing itself should happen in Android Studio or another environment? where do I create the backend classes and objects? how do I connect it to the data store service and perform queries?

Main question- how the backend creation process exactly goes, and once I'll connect the dots- where is the information on how to develop it (classes creation etc).

thanks!

Comment: thanks, but I already know these things.
I have experince in the field, and deveolped android applications about 3 years ago, long before Cloud Endpoints and Android Studio were exist and common.
My question, like the Tags I put, related specifically to the backend creation in Android Studio with cloud endpoints using the data store, and how it all goes out.

Comment: I'm sorry, haven't seen the tags

Answer (score 0):

You can do your development inside of Android Studio. Just have 2 seperate modules inside the same project; one for the android app and one for the backend.

You've integrated the sayHi example and you've said it works. Have you been able to call it from your app? If so, just look at the example, make sure you understand how it works and expand on it.

For you backend it would be best to use some sort of Service Layer - Business Layer - Data Layer design pattern. The endpoints themselves would be in the Service layer. The business layer will manipulate the inputs and outputs. And the Data Layer would be your connection to GAE. I personally use Objectify in combination with the datastore but you don't have to.